# "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript in above-the-fold content" even though all JS is at the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, pagespeed

The page in question is live at peppyburro.com/sandboxindex. I have been particularly careful to ensure all my `<script>` tags are out of the way of the rest of the page. To ensure that, all those tags sit together at the very end of the document, just above the closing `<body>` tag. And yet Google says it's blocking the above-the-fold content. What else can be done to eliminate this issue?

Here's what it looks like currently:

```
<body>

<!-- rest of the page -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sandboxassets_mbr/tether/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sandboxassets_mbr/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sandboxassets_mbr/smooth-scroll/SmoothScroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sandboxassets_mbr/dropdown/js/script.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sandboxassets_mbr/touchSwipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sandboxassets_mbr/bootstrap-carousel-swipe/bootstrap-carousel-swipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sandboxassets_mbr/jarallax/jarallax.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sandboxassets_mbr/theme/js/script.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sandboxassets/js/pb.min.js"></script>    

<iframe name="oauth2relay568119477" id="oauth2relay568119477" src="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay?parent=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.peppyburro.com&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_GB.D6BJotTTK3k.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCMhm9y_bVe3QuOa8vncNGxJUzV-Tw#rpctoken=888376000&amp;forcesecure=1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; top: -100px;"></iframe><iframe id="rufous-sandbox" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none;" title="Twitter analytics iframe"></iframe><script id="PIN_1487351100480.f.callback[1]" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://log.pinterest.com/?guid=1hSbMAVfYDeC&amp;tv=2016111001&amp;type=pidget&amp;sub=www&amp;button_count=0&amp;follow_count=0&amp;pin_count=0&amp;profile_count=0&amp;board_count=0&amp;lang=en&amp;via=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.peppyburro.com%2Fsandboxindex&amp;callback=PIN_1487351100480.f.callback[1]"></script>

</body>
```

There does exist some tiny bit of social media API call-scripts in the header but Google specifically named files mentioned above as culprits.

Comment: You could combine all scripts in one script and load it async to increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

You do have some Facebook SDK, Twitter SDK, and Google Analytics script tags fairly high up in the hierarchy. Depending on what code is using them, it should be safe to move those blocks all down to the bottom of the page (above your own JavaScript files).

I'd recommend moving one at a time, starting with the GA one so as to easily identify if any change causes bugs or errors.

Comment: I admit I have those scripts in my header tag, but those aren't the only ones Google is fussing about. I'm mainly baffled by the scripts that I mentioned in my question, such as JQuery which are way down where my body tag ends and yet Google holding them responsible for the ATF rendering delay.

Comment: So in the "Show how to fix" section it lists these files in the footer?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: Hmm that's very odd. You could try adding "async" attributes to each script tag.

Comment: Will try doing that and get back to you. Thanks for the tip!